# HTML5 email input type Email does not accept anything

Tags: html, xhtml, email-validation

I have 2 different xhtml pages. The first one has a similar content with the second one but when I submit the page, email input in the second code does not except any value and says "Please match the requested format". What could be the problem here ?

first.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/info_page.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["res_sign_up"]["password1"].value;
var y=document.forms["res_sign_up"]["password2"].value;
if ( x != y )
  {
  alert("Sifreleriniz ayni olmalidir.");
  return false;
  }
}
    </script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="css/custom.js"></script>
    <form name="res_sign_up" action="cgi-bin/res_edit_profile.py" onsubmit="return validateForm()"
      method="POST">
      <div id="baslik"> <img src="css/images/profil_duzenle_baslik.png" id="img1" />
        <a href="http://twitter.com/me" class="img2" title="T"></a> </div>
      <br />
      E-mail adresi:
      <p><input type="email" class="text1" name="email" required="required" /></p>
      <p>Şifre:</p>
      <p><input type="password" class="text1" name="password1" required="required" /></p>
      <p>Şifre (tekrar):</p>
      <p><input type="password" class="text1" name="password2" required="required" /></p>
      <p>Restoran Adı:</p>
      <p><input type="text" class="text1" name="isim" required="required" /></p>
      <p>Telefon No:</p>
      <p><input type="tel" class="text1" name="telno" maxlength="10" required="required" /></p>
      <p>İl:</p>
      <p><input type="text" class="text1" name="il" required="required" /></p>
      <p>İlçe:</p>
      <p><input type="text" class="text1" name="ilce" required="required" /></p>
      <p>Semt:</p>
      <p><input type="text" class="text1" name="semt" required="required" /></p>
      <p>Tam Adres:</p>
      <p><input type="text" class="text1" name="tamadres" required="required" /></p>
      <p>Restoran Türü:</p>
      <p>
        <select name="tur" required="required" class="list">
          <option value="cafe">Cafe</option>
          <option value="cinmutfak">Çin Mutfağı</option>
          <option value="deniz">Deniz Ürünler</option>
          <option value="dunya">Dünya Mutfağı</option>
          <option value="ev">Ev Yemekleri</option>
          <option value="fastfood">Fast Food</option>
          <option value="gurme">Gurme</option>
          <option value="italyan">İtalyan Mutfağı</option>
          <option value="japon">Japon Mutfağı</option>
          <option value="kebapturk">Kebap ve Türk Mutfağı</option>
          <option value="kofte">Köfte</option>
          <option value="pasta">Pasta ve Tatlı</option>
          <option value="pide">Pide</option>
          <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>Çalışma Saatleri:</p>
      <p>Pazartesi: <input type="text" class="text1" name="saatler1" value="09:00-22.30"
          required="required" /></p>
      <p> Salı:          <input type="text" class="text1" name="saatler2" value="09:00-22.30"
          required="required" /></p>
      <p> Çarşamba:<input type="text" class="text1" name="saatler3" value="09:00-22.30"
          required="required" /></p>
      <p> Perşembe: <input type="text" class="text1" name="saatler4" value="09:00-22.30"
          required="required" /></p>
      <p> Cuma:       <input type="text" class="text1" name="saatler5" value="09:00-22.30" /></p>
      <p> Cumartesi:<input type="text" class="text1" name="saatler6" value="11:00-22.00"
          required="required" /></p>
      <p> Pazar:       <input type="text" class="text1" name="saatler7" value="-"
          required="required" /></p>
      <p>Rezervasyon Durumu:</p>
      <p>
        <select name="rezervasyon" required="required" class="list">
          <option value="hici">Hafta içi yapılabilir.</option>
          <option value="hsonu">Hafta sonu yapılabilir.</option>
          <option value="htum">Hafta içi ve hafta sonu yapılabilir.</option>
          <option value="yapma">Yapılamaz</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>Ödeme Seçenekleri:</p>
      <input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="payment" value="Nakit" />Nakit<br />
      <input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="payment" value="Kredi Karti" />Kredi
      Kartı<br />
      <input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="payment" value="SmarTicket" />SmarTicket<br />
      <input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="payment" value="Ticket Yemek Ceki" />Ticket
      Yemek Çeki<br />
      <input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="payment" value="PassCard" />PassCard<br />
      <input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="payment" value="Sodexho Yemek Ceki" />Sodexho
      Yemek Çeki<br />
      <input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="payment" value="Multinet" />Multinet<br />
      <input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="payment" value="SetCard" />SetCard<br />
      <input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="payment" value="Winwin Yemek Ceki" />Winwin
      Yemek Çeki
      <p><a href="history.go%28-1%29;return%20true;" class="back" title="T"></a><input
          type="image" class="onay1" formmethod="post" name="myclicker" value="" /></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

second.xhtml(does not submit any values):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>login_page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login_page.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="css/custom.js"></script>
    <form name="res_sign_up" action="cgi-bin/login_check.py"
      method="POST"><img src="css/images/hosgeldiniz.png" /> <img src="css/images/logo.png" />
      <input type="email" pattern="E-mail Adresi" class="login1" name="email" required="required" />
      <input type="password" class="login1" name="password" required="required" />
      <img class="login4" alt="remember" src="css/images/beni_hatirla.png" /> <input
        type="checkbox" class="styled" name="remember" /> <a href="http://twitter.com/me"
        class="login3" title="T"></a> <input type="image" class="login5" formmethod="post"
        name="myclicker" value="" /> <a href="http://twitter.com/me" class="login6"
        title="T"></a> </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second form you have the following:

```
<input type="email" pattern="E-mail Adresi" class="login1" name="email" required="required" />
```

You have added the `pattern="E-mail Adresi"` which means the input must match that regular expression. And no valid email address will match the regular expression 'E-mail Adresi'. I suspect you wanted to add a hint text using `placeholder="E-mail Adresi"`.

Comment: Thank a lot mate, I don't know how i missed it. Now, it works flawless! You saved my project